# iis 7 \ windows 7 asp.net access is denied

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7.5, access-denied

I am trying a very simple action of saving a file into a folder of mine. I am hosting my application on windows 7 using iis 7. When I try saving my file I get the following error:

Access to the path 'C:\MyWebsite\MyFolder' is denied

I am not impersonating, I have given network service full control on the folder. What can be causing this?

Thank you!

Sorry: My mistake, apprently I have an installation of iis 7 (not 7.5)

Comment: the hour is really late and I am stuck on something ridiculous. What am I missing, how is that against Stack Overflow's rules?

Comment: You said that you gave network service the necessary rights but is that the user that the app pool is running under?

Comment: @Gert curious why you feel this is somehow a violation of the site? I would be interested to know for my own personal knowledge.

Comment: @spinon, yes it is. I double checked. I can see that from some reason the folder has the read only attribute on it. Can't seem to get rid of it though.

Comment: Can you delete the folder and recreate it? If you aren't the owner of the folder it might not let you change the permissions of it.

Comment: @spinon - Is it a programming related or a server related question? From the FAQ: *Networking, servers, or maintaining other people's PCs and contains no source code, ask on Server Fault.*

Comment: @Gert yeah I see your point. It is kind of on the edge there. I have to be honest I might have hit up here as well but it is questionable. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @spinon - Let's see if it gets to live or die. :)

Comment: The network admins at my office wouldn't be able to answer this questions, and i feel they are representative of many (most?) admins. I find there is a distinction between "retail" software configuration (with volumous documentation) and custom software configuration. Would you expect an admin to edit a web.config file to change your application's WCF bindings to use bi-directional Transport level authentication with ssl server and client certs? If your admin can do that, please, tell me where i should be looking to hire.

Comment: None of the above seem to help. I gave the folder the correct permissions, I set the right owner...  nothing helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you never solved this, something else to check - are you overwriting an existing file? If so, make sure it's not read-only. That will give you this same error, and none of the usual permission changes will fix it.

I had a similar setup and had tried everything. That finally did it.